# why does terminal start with '/Users/nicholas/.zshrc:source:75: no such file or directory:' after uninstalling ohmyzsh?

Tags: oh-my-zsh

i've uninstalled ohmyzsh and now everytime i start my termial it says this:

```
Last login: Sat Feb  6 13:53:16 on ttys001  
/Users/nicholas/.zshrc:source:75: no such file or directory: /Users/nicholas/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh  
nicholas@macbook ~%
```

How to fix it?

(original screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnQWl.png))

Comment: That file, `/Users/nicholas/.zshrc` mentions `/Users/nicholas/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh` on line 75. Edit the file, remove this mention of oh-my-zsh from line 75.

Comment: Also, instead of posting a screenshot or a link to it, it would be better if you copied the actual text of the error message and posted that instead. The reason for this is that any other person in the future that has the same error message would then have a chance to find it using Google.

Comment: how do i edit it if i remove it?

Comment: Use a text editor to edit that file.

Comment: thank you, I commented 75 line in /Users/nicholas/.zshrc and it helped

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen strong agree - unlikely here, but using screenshots is also frequently used when someone wants to hide something else in a source that would be easily evident if they shared a link - DeepL, a good translator, has a "catch text on screen" feature which is extremely useful for the OP here, and for quickly adding linked sources to anyone who's trying to hide things by impeding finding them!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- open .zshrc
  If you can't find find .zshrc, then type "ls -a" in terminal to get hidden files
- After opening .zshrc file, comment the line 75 by appending "#"

[image: Check this image]

Comment: Note: you can also use CMD+SHIFT+PERIOD(.) to toggle the hidden stuff in the Finder on MacOS as of a few versions now

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to open the terminal on your mac.
2. Then type "**ls -a**" now you can see all .zsh files on your macOS
3. Delete .zsh file using this command **"rm .zsh"** then hit the enter.

Answer (score 0):

move `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` after the path variable. So it looks like below. save and reopen terminal.

```
export ZSH="/Users/<username>/.oh-my-zsh"
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$ZSH:$PATH
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```